# VideoView in a HorizontalRecyclerView shows Wallpaper while swiping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

When I scroll `Horizontal RecyclerView` while playing a video, the edges of `videoView` shows the wallpaper.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eH6b.jpg)

I tried `vieoView`, `ExoPlayer`, `surfaceView`. But all shows the same problem. when the `videoView` replaced with `imageView` the problem could be solved.

```
<hu.lacroix82.stretchtopviewlibrary.StretchTopScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/stretchTopView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@color/background_main">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            ......
            .......
            .......
```

Comment: How is `VideoView` laid out? Provide a hierarchy.

Comment: @Abbas please check the hierarchy.

Comment: OS of Test device you are using?

Comment: `Android 7.0` -  Nougat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Check which theme you have used for this activity. Whether is it a transparent theme? Because you have tried multiple video playing library and the same issue is rising so I don't think this is an issue from the coding side. this must be from your activity theme so change your activity theme to some dark theme with a solid color. let me know if issue solved or not?

Comment: I changed the theme into `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. now shows a black color instead of blue wallpaper.

Comment: Because there is a transparent portion between your 2 video view that is why it displays black color this is the only issue of transparency so make changes according

Comment: it worked ...but video player taking a second to load on swiping ..is there any solution for that

Comment: You can precache necessity data before swiping and you can use that preloaded data without any delay.